# Create Custom Installer through Visual studion 2012 in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, installation

[image]

Hi,

I have to create one installer as shown in picture. I have tried with visual studio installer template and I have seen that there is one installer class also. But It's not giving same design as shown in my picture.

When user will click on install button on that time it should install project and other button it will document.

Hope I'm clear with my requriement.

Comment: You're somehow formulated your task. Now what about your question? What is your question exactly?

Comment: how to achieve this through Visual studio installer template.